# Drop a value iplace from series derived from data frame pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I just came across this code below and i am wondering why the value is not dropped from the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

print (df)
df.Brand.drop(axis=0,index = 0,inplace=True)
print (df)
```

Can some one explain me what is happening here?
PS:- I know how to delete `drop()` values but want to know why nothing is changing.

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do. What's your expected output?

Comment: I was expecting the value of 'Honda Civic' to be replaced by NaN in the data frame.

Comment: Then `df.loc[0, 'Brand'] = np.nan`. You can't modify a slice inplace.

Answer (score 0):

The value at index `0` of `Brand` column is getting dropped. Have a look at this:

```
In [1240]: df.Brand.drop(axis=0,index = 0,inplace=True)
In [1242]: df.Brand
Out[1242]: 
1    Toyota Corolla
2        Ford Focus
3           Audi A4
Name: Brand, dtype: object
```

But I agree with you that when you `print(df)`, it shows like nothing happened:

```
In [1243]: df
Out[1243]: 
            Brand  Price
0     Honda Civic  22000
1  Toyota Corolla  25000
2      Ford Focus  27000
3         Audi A4  35000
```

**Seems like a bug.**

If you instead do this:

```
In [1246]: df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

In [1247]: df
Out[1247]: 
            Brand  Price
0     Honda Civic  22000
1  Toyota Corolla  25000
2      Ford Focus  27000
3         Audi A4  35000

In [1248]: df.Brand = df.Brand.drop(axis=0,index = 0)

In [1249]: df
Out[1249]: 
            Brand  Price
0             NaN  22000
1  Toyota Corolla  25000
2      Ford Focus  27000
3         Audi A4  35000
```

The result is as expected.

Comment: How to find out why it did not work in the first approach?

Comment: It did work in the first approach.If you print the `series` individually, in this case the `Brand` column, you can see that the `Honda Civic` is deleted. Though it does not show when we print the whole `dataframe` which seems buggy.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I can't reproduce your first example (`In[1240]` to `In[1242]`) and  I can't imagine how this should work - how can you drop a single cell within a dataframe? You can only drop whole rows or columns. Dropping means removing the value **and the index**.

Comment: @Stef My pandas version is `'1.1.0'`. What version are you on?

Comment: @MayankPorwal `1.2.0`

Comment: @Stef You can check in version `1.1.0` that first example works fine.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I believe you but as I wrote above it makes no sense to me to `drop` an element from a series that is part of a dataframe. What should be the index of the remaining columns in the dataframe? So I think the behavior you showed is just a bug that was fixed in a newer version of pandas.